# php one variable on different pages

Tags: php, mysql

i have a variable $cartTotal in cart.php page i want to use that same $cartTotal in another page and want to insert value of $cartTotal in table

how to do this 
?

thanks

Comment: With sessions or value submission via forms/parameters. Search for in example `$_POST, $_GET or $_SESSION`.

Comment: Smamatti .. please give an example using session to transfer variable $cartTotal in another page

Comment: For the lazy programmer: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+session+tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to give a variable to anothe page, i think you don't use any frameworks, so I'll explain just the basic ways:

At first, start a Session. At the very first of your script, add this:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

There must not be any other code before this, not even whitespace.
So now, you can set Session-Variables like this:

```
$_SESSION['cartTotal'] = $cartTotal;
```

The Variable $_SESSION['cartTotal'] will now be available on every page, you can use it just like a normal variable.

The second facility is, to give a variable to another page by it's link with the GET-Method. E.G. set up your link like this:

```
<a href="site.php?cartTutorial=<?php echo $cartTutorial ?>">Link</a>
```

The Variable will be available in $_GET['cartTutorial'] but only in the next page and just by clicking this link. Also the GET-Method ist just good for simple variables, only text and numbers for example, arrays cannot be set.

Third possibility is the POST-Method, but it just works with a form and is just interesting if you are using one.

Simpliest possibility in my opinion is to make a session-variable.

Comment: +1 for taking the time of writing this answer

Comment: thank you for detailed answer ..the same i were doing .. but actual problem was somewhere else in the code .. problem is solved now thanks

Comment: Next time: Post your code, so we could also find mistakes like this :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can declare it into the "landing" page as `GLOBAL` and also include in the landing page the file where `$cartTotal` is declared.
2. You can use the `$_SESSION` array-variable or something like that (`$_GET` or `$_POST)`

Comment: i wan to do this using $_session but i need a sample code or example thanks

Comment: You can find so much example on the internet...

Answer (score 0):

Great tutorials for quickly understanding $_SESSION, $_GET and, $_POST can be found on w3schools.com:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Good luck!